# What happens to binary files in file_get_contents?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to read a file in php and store it as a varbinary in sql server. The process works for text files, but I'm still having trouble with images.

I'm using the following lines to read the file contents into a string, but I'm not sure that that's not where my problem lies:

```
$data = NULL;
$validators = NULL;
if($file = file_save_upload('file', $validators, FALSE, 0)){
  $data = file_get_contents($file->getFileUri());
  $filename = $file->getFilename();
}
```

Then I pass the $data string to a prepared statement:

```
$conn = $this->_get_connection();

$sql = "      
  EXEC JC_Update_Document_SP
    ...
    ?,
    ...;
";

$file_input = [
  [$data, NULL, NULL, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARBINARY],
];

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $file_input);

if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === false){
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

where the `$data` field feeds into a varbinary column in a stored procedure in the database.

Another method I tried involved converting the `$data` varchar to a varbinary(max) field in the database, but either way, I get back a broken image.

So my question is this... is file_get_contents messing up my binary data? How would I read the image file and upload it to the database for later retrieval?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe there is an encoding conflict between the db and the file system?  Does the binary image in the db look the same as the output of file_get_contents on the file system?

Comment: also, you might want to base64_encode() the data before saving to db, and base64_decode() it on the way out, if you aren't already doing that. and maybe try blob instead of varbinary.

Comment: I ended up using the built-in function `bin2hex` on my $data. Now it works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) function. I'm still unclear on why this is needed, but it gets the job done.